# How to add class CSS after ng-click to parent element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

There is HTML code:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <input ng-click="addClass()" type="checkbox"> 
  </span>
</div>
```

How I can add CSS class to parent element `div` after click at input?

I tried:

```
ng-click="addClass($event)"
```

Angular JS:

```
$scope.addClass = function (event){
   event.parent('div').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `ng-class` in your case, maintain a `scope` variable which will used in `ng-class` expression, there is no need to use jQuery while you have directive like `ng-class` which makes your life easy.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-class="{active: active}">
  <span>
    <input ng-click="active!= active" type="checkbox"> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I use HTML template in `ng-view` here this code does not work. I get error: `TypeError: g.setClass is not a function`

Comment: In console I see how is changed `class` without value

Comment: @Hamed you can not see the value changed in console..please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76764/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-hamed I'll guid what exactly needs to do..

Comment: I did like as: `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.major">  <label class="checkbox-label" ng-class="{active: formData.major}"></label>`

Comment: @Hamed could you please come on chat